# Do we have to use mysql_real_escape_string() while working with sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysql-real-escape-string

Please look at the codes below:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
```

Do I have to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function while I'm setting `$username` value too? Is there any threat here if I don't?

**Attention:** I used PDO while I want to work with MySQL.

Comment: if you use PDO, you can use prepare instead of needing to escape the variables when executing query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need to escape it in any way there. You only need to escape text if you are concatenating it with other text where certain characters may have a special meaning. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: are you agree with @asprin? Being a SQL statement in a session can harm the application? Is it not better to filter all SQLs even when storing values in the sessions?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi There is no SQL statement in the session; not in the code you've posted. Moreover, "a SQL statement in a session can harm the application" is nonsense - sessions and SQL are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Moh Don't escape data before it's necessary! Yes, you may have data in there which, if used naively in an SQL query, would cause SQL injection. But that doesn't mean you have to escape it while storing it in the session, because it can do no harm there. Escape when necessary, no sooner, no later. If you're using PDO prepared statements you don't need to escape at all.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to, use it only when you want to escape the characters for entering it to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql_real_escape_string() is used for security purposes, so users couldn't do SQL Injection. If you aren't using `$_SESSION['user_name']` or `$username` for database, then you won't need to use it. You can read more here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

mysql_real_escpae_string() adds backslash to each special character.

Also, you should check some of SQL injection examples, so you get a idea how it's done, and what exactly mysql_real_escape_string() is preventing - http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html .

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to as session data can only be manipulated on the server.

If you **KNOW** you have data in there that is to be used in a query and has characters that need escaping then obviously you should ensure that takes place.

Any values you store in sessions that contain any qry language like 'OR 1 = 1'  is bascially down to poor application design IMO - any values in session that could open you up to security lapses are your own fault - just make sure it can't be done.

Comment: Huh? It's perfectly common to store user-supplied data in the session which needs to be escaped if and when used in a query or elsewhere...?!